# Using hashCat with a RAR file?

Tags: linux, hash, passwords, ocl, hashcat

I'm pretty stumped, is it actually possible to use hashcat for a RAR file? The [forum](http://hashcat.net/forum/archive/index.php?thread-4402.html) says "yes" and points to a [sample](http://pastebin.com/2ew5eAG1)...

They appear to be calling:

```
./oclHashcat64.bin -m 12500 hash -w 3 -a 3 ha?l?l?l?l?l
```

So far, so good.. So I go grab jtr and run rar2john, which gives me;

```
test.rar:$RAR3$*1*1234561234561234*e1111111*22222222*33333333*0*/home/test.rar*77*33:1::testClip.wmv
```

I've tried every permutation of this in place of the 'hash' in the command, but I always get `Line-length exception`

Has anyone gotten this to work successfuly? I noticed that the RAR type is 1 -- which is -p, instead of 0 (-ph).. Is that my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the docs are buried in the release notes, but for anyone that stumbles on this.. -p is not yet supported, only -ph.

Comment: could you crack that using JTR